# Does foreach remove from C# BlockingCollection?

Tags: c#, foreach, behavior, blockingqueue, blockingcollection

does anyone know if, when iterating on a C# BlockingCollection<>, the elements are taken from the collection, in the same way that BlockingCollection.Take() does for example?

```
BlockingCollection<int> q = new BlockingCollection<int>();
[...]
foreach(int i in q)
{
    //does q still contain i?
}
```

Thanks

EDIT: Of course I meant BlockingCollection, but for some reason got BlockingQueue in my head and used that.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The `BlockingCollection<T>` enumerator does NOT remove items from the collection.

However, the enumerator returned from [`BlockingCollection<T>.GetConsumingEnumerable()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287186%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) *DOES* remove items from the collection.

Answer (score 2):

`foreach` simply enumerates across a collection. It never removes anything from any collection.

Comment: And actually if I'm not mistaken, manipulating the collection inside a foreach is forbidden and will fail at runtime.

Comment: That is simply not true. Consider, for example, using `foreach` with [`BlockingCollection<T>.GetConsumingEnumerable()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287186%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) The issue is that because `foreach` simply calls methods in `IEnumerator<T>` the effect depends on the specific implementation of `IEnumerator<T>` that's being called - so you can make no claims about what the effect of using `foreach` will be.

Comment: Sorry, Matthew, you're wrong. `foreach` isn't removing anything - it's the `IEnumerator<T>` which is removing items in this very specific and very unusual case.

Comment: Using `foreach` can have the side-effect of removing items from a collection, which is my point. I think this point is important in the context of the OP's question which wasn't *"does foreach remove elements from a collection?"* but rather *"when iterating on a C# BlockingQueue<>, are elements taken from the collection?"*

Comment: @MatthewWatson: name one other enumerator that removes from a standard collection. This possibility is simply not worth mentioning.

Comment: The OP seems to be talking about a BlockingCollection (although he referred to it as a BlockingQueue) so my opinion is that this is definitely relevant and therefore it is indeed worth mentioning. I agree in the general case (i.e. ALL other cases!) then it isn't relevant. But I'm responding to the OP's actual question rather than something theoretical.

Answer (score 0):

There is no `BlockingQueue<T>` in the .NET libraries.

Assuming

1. You're talking about `BlockingCollection<T>`: No. using foreach calls the `GetEnumerator` method, which returns an `IEnumerator`. Standard implementations of an `IEnumerator` simply enumerate through the elements in the collection without any observable side effects. Since [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267312%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) doesn't say otherwise regarding `BlockingCollection<T>` specifically, it is safe to assume that this specific implementation also has no observable side effects.
2. You're talking about a third-party library: You'll have to check its implementation, but I think it's safe to assume it doesn't remove anything from the collection.

**Edit**: Actually, because `BlockingCollection` wraps around an `IProducerConsumerCollection<T>`, `BlockingCollection` uses the enumerator of the underlying (internal) collection. None of the `IProducerConsumerCollection<T>` implementations provided by .NET modify the collection.